# collect_set on array type with group by in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have below table which contains duplicates on id with array of values for each id and I want to find out unique values for each id, how to do that?

```
CREATE TABLE test(
id string,
values array<string>)
```

When I run below command, it throws error as `collect_set` only support primitive type values.

```
select id, collect_set(values) from ts group by id;
```

**ERROR:**

> FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are
>   accepted but array was passed as parameter 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error message says `Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array was passed as parameter 1.`, you need to convert the array to String before using it.

You can achieve the same using `explode()` function. Something like:

```
select 
  id, 
  collect_set(tokens) 
FROM
  ts LATERAL VIEW explode(values) x AS tokens
group by
  id;
```

Comment: should not be possible something like: `select id, collect_set(explode values)  as values_list` being `value` an `array`?

Comment: After a lot of research, Finally, this solution works. Thanks @Ambarish.

Answer (score 1):

Another informal way of solving this issue, especially in nested queries with many group by and collect_set is to concatenate the array into one string using **concat_ws("", values)**.

```
select id, collect_set(concat_ws("", values)) from ts group by id;
```